# my vba is not working on powerpoint

Tags: vba

I am making a quiz with an answer box and a check my answer box.

I put the code in and then when I put in the answer it says "wrong try again" and when I write nothing in the box then it says "correct well done."

The code I put in is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = motherboard Then
    MsgBox "Correct. Well done!"
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong answer. Try again."
End If
```

Comment: Is `motherboard` a variable that you're not showing, or literal text?  I'm also betting that you're not using `Option Explicit` at the start of your code.

Comment: What is Option Eplicit I have just started using this and I have no idea how to use it please can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "motherboard" Then
    MsgBox "Correct. Well done!"
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong answer. Try again."
End If
```

Without Defining motherboard in another location, I am assuming you want the Literal answer to be the Text "motherboard" So you need to add quotes around the word.

The reason it accepts your answer when there isn't one is because when you add a variable that isn't defined it is defaulted with a value of nothing. So when you enter nothing it is a match to a variable that also equals nothing. By adding the quotes it makes it look for exactly that word.

You also might want to add some kind of filters to the incoming text to make it more likely for a correct answer that may have an extra space for a capital letter to be excepted.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Trim(LCase(TextBox1.Value)) = "motherboard" Then
    MsgBox "Correct. Well done!"
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong answer. Try again."
End If
```

Adding the LCase command will make all entered text lower case. And Adding the Trim command will remove all white space before and after the word.

Comment: Instead of just providing a code dump with no explanation, it would be better to *explain* to the user what you've corrected, and why their code isn't working.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Was getting there....

Comment: Thanks a lot user2140261 I have understood why I need to put the quotation marks around the word you really help thanks